# Differences between cyclic prefix, postfix and zeropadding

Tags: ofdm

I was looking into details of OFDM and how the CP is copied last few sample of OFDM and placed in the beginning to cause circular convolution and mitigate is. My understanding is this cyclic prefix helps. What if we do post fix. That is we take place it at the end of OFDM symbol? Would that work? And what if we do zero padding instead would that mitigate isi?

Comment: This is a bit broad. You say you know that the cyclic prefix helps. Do you know *how*? If not, this should be your actual question (that you should try to answer yourself first). If you do know *how* the CP helps, so, how does your question come to be? Other than that, there's a lot of questions on how the CP is different from zero-padding on here, and I don't want to close your question as duplicate, but right now, it is.

Comment: That may only answer the zero padding and not the post fix. I still don't know if post fix work. Thank you.

Comment: then edit your question to be about the postfix only. Also, as I've already pointed out: You still skip the part where you explain why your question remains after understanding *how* the CP helps, and that's (still) the answer to your question. So, even after fixing your question to only be about postfix, it's still too broad, because we don't know what you can't knowledge-transfer from cyclic prefix to cyclic suffix. Any answer that would explain this would start with explaining how the CP helps, and that's just a duplicate effort.

Comment: Note that if, while/after reading *why* and *how* the CP helps, you have a problem in understanding you're **more** than welcome to ask precisely about what you don't understand. But please understand that asking "what's the difference between cyclic prefix and suffix? I haven't looked into either!" is too broad, as it expects us to reproduce a significant amount of easily existing literature, including answers already given on this site!

Comment: @Tyrone both cyclic prefix and suffix work the same way if you can take the correct FFT window to avoid intersymbol interference. To echo Marcus, we are eager to help, but we do not want to waste our time writing long answers to repeat basic stuff that can be found by a simple search. This would be different if you ask a question about why you think that cyclic suffix is different from cyclic prefix and how you think the suffix does not work the same way.